# Android launch a fragment within a dialog fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a dialog fragment and I need to launch a fragment within this dialog fragment. This means my fragment should occupy the same window as that of dialog fragment. How do I do this? This is my dialog fragment code -

```
public class CallDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.call_dialog_fragment, container, false);


            return view;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use fragment transaction and add another dialog fragment. and add to back stack.

Answer (score 0):

you can use coordinator layout for dialog-fragment.. when you drag layout to  upper side it will be your new fragment. and when you drag to down it will be your dialog fragment.

here is the xml code..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            local:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            local:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            local:expandedTitleMarginBottom="22dp"
            local:expandedTitleMarginStart="20dp"
            local:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
            local:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressfull"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_preview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                local:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image_preview"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbarIcon"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                local:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/addbtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        local:borderWidth="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        local:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="24dp">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

2. fragment_image_slider.xml

   > ```
   > <LinearLayout
   >     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   >     android:layout_width="match_parent"
   >     android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >     android:orientation="vertical">
   >
   >     <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
   >         android:id="@+id/viewpager"
   >         android:layout_width="match_parent"
   >         android:layout_height="match_parent">
   >     </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
   >
   > </LinearLayout>
   > ```

here is the java code..

```
public class SlideshowDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private String TAG = SlideshowDialogFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    private ArrayList<ItemCategories> images;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private MyViewPagerAdapter myViewPagerAdapter;
    private String lblCount, lblTitle, lblDate;
    private int selectedPosition = 0;
    private CardView cardView;
    private Context mContext;

    public static SlideshowDialogFragment newInstance() {
        SlideshowDialogFragment fragmentFullScreen = new SlideshowDialogFragment();
        return fragmentFullScreen;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_image_slider, container, false);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(viewPager,
                new OnApplyWindowInsetsListener() {
                    @Override
                    public WindowInsetsCompat onApplyWindowInsets(View v,
                                                                  WindowInsetsCompat insets) {
                        insets = ViewCompat.onApplyWindowInsets(v, insets);
                        if (insets.isConsumed()) {
                            return insets;
                        }

                        boolean consumed = false;
                        for (int i = 0, count = viewPager.getChildCount(); i <  count; i++) {
                            ViewCompat.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(viewPager.getChildAt(i), insets);
                            if (insets.isConsumed()) {
                                consumed = true;
                            }
                        }
                        return consumed ? insets.consumeSystemWindowInsets() : insets;
                    }
                });


        images = (ArrayList<ItemCategories>) getArguments().getSerializable("images");
        selectedPosition = getArguments().getInt("position");

        Log.e(TAG, "position: " + selectedPosition);
        Log.e(TAG, "images size: " + images.size());

        myViewPagerAdapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter();
        viewPager.setAdapter(myViewPagerAdapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(viewPagerPageChangeListener);

        setCurrentItem(selectedPosition);

        getArguments().remove("position");
        getArguments().remove("images");

        return v;
    }

        private void setCurrentItem(int position) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(position, false);
            displayMetaInfo(selectedPosition);
        }

        //  page change listener
        ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener viewPagerPageChangeListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            displayMetaInfo(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

        }
    };

    private void displayMetaInfo(int position) {

        lblCount = (position + 1) + " of " + images.size();
        ItemCategories image = images.get(position);
        lblTitle = "" + image.getCategoryItem();
        lblDate = "" + image.getUrlThumb();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.MyMaterialThemeFull);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }

    // adapter
    public class MyViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;


        public MyViewPagerAdapter() {
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.image_fullscreen_preview, container, false);

            ImageView imageViewPreview = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_preview);

            Toolbar toolbarIcon = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbarIcon);
            ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbarIcon);
            ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

            CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar =
                    (CollapsingToolbarLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);


            AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.appbar);

            DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
            int screenHeight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;

            CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams lp = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams)appBarLayout.getLayoutParams();
            lp.height = screenHeight;

            toolbarIcon.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Fragment prev = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("slideshow");
                    if (prev != null) {
                        DialogFragment dialogFullScreen = (DialogFragment) prev;
                        dialogFullScreen.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            });


            ItemCategories image = images.get(position);


            Glide.with(getActivity()).load(image.getUrlThumb())
                    .thumbnail(0.5f)
                    .crossFade()
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .into(imageViewPreview);

            collapsingToolbar.setTitle(lblTitle);
            container.addView(view);

            return view;
        }



        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return images.size();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object obj) {
            return view == ((View) obj);
        }


        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            container.removeView((View) object);
        }

    }
}
```

just copy this code and you will know what i am talking about